# I installed a whole bunch of lib6 packages and can't upgrade or use --fix-broken

Tags: package-management, upgrade, 64-bit, 32-bit

Whenever I upgrade I get:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-6-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not installed
 libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.24-11+deb9u4) but it is not installed
 libc6-xen:i386 : PreDepends: libc6:i386 (= 2.24-11+deb9u3) but 2.24-11+deb9u4 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I 'sudo apt install --fix-broken' I get:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.
125 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,653 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,178 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

(Reading database ... 161213 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev-i386_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev-i386 (2.24-11+deb9u4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/bits', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64:i386 2.24-11+deb9u4
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-dev-i386', but I get the same error.

What do I do about

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the file, `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb` it is only a cached file. Then run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt --fix-broken install` ...

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt install --reinstall libc6-dev-i386` did it.